# Edit script so it only creates shortcuts for files that exist?

Tags: batch-file, shortcut

so I have this script to create shortcuts for files I have to check, the problem is it creates the shortcut weather the file exists OR not. Any way to stop it from creating shortcuts for files that don't exist YET?

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\file_shortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Firm\F1000\file_to_check.pdf" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: Check if they exist first, e.g. `If Exist "C:\Firm\F1000\file_to_check.pdf" ("%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //B //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%" & Del "%SCRIPT%")`

Comment: would you mind showing me where exactly that would go in my script? im not well versed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way for you to implement this would be like this:

```batch-file
@Set "TARGET=C:\Firm\F1000\file_to_check.pdf"
@If Not Exist "%TARGET%" GoTo :EOF
@Set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
@(  Echo Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    Echo strLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\file_shortcut.lnk"
    Echo Set objLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(strLinkFile^)
    Echo objLink.TargetPath = "%TARGET%"
    Echo objLink.Save) 1> "%SCRIPT%"
@"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //B //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%"
@Del "%SCRIPT%"
```

If you had several shortcuts to create, and you knew that the `check` directory already existed on the users' desktop, you could use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop). In the following example, I've used three different targets, `"C:\Firm\F1000\file_to_check.pdf"`, `"C:\Somewhere\ADirectory\somefile.ext"`, and `"D:\Elsewhere\filename.ext"`. You can just list yours in the same manner as below:

```batch-file
@Set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
@(  Echo Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    Echo strLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\"+Wscript.Arguments(1^)+".lnk"
    Echo Set objLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(strLinkFile^)
    Echo objLink.TargetPath = Wscript.Arguments(0^)
    Echo objLink.Save
) 1> "%SCRIPT%"
@For %%G In (
    "C:\Firm\F1000\file_to_check.pdf"
    "C:\Somewhere\ADirectory\somefile.ext"
    "D:\Elsewhere\filename.ext"
) Do @If Exist %%G "%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //B //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%" %%G "%%~nG"
@Del "%SCRIPT%"
```

*In both examples, I've removed some of those `%RANDOM%` parts of the string, I do not think it's likely that you'll have an existing `.vbs` file in `%TEMP%`, which you'll need in the future, and which already matches that generated random name.*

Comment: The second script uses the same name as the target file, but obviously with a different extension ,`.lnk`. e.g. `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\file_to_check.lnk` opens `C:\Firm\F1000\file_to_check.pdf`, `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\somefile.lnk` opens `C:\Somewhere\ADirectory\somefile.ext`, and `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\filename.lnk` opens `D:\Elsewhere\filename.ext`.

Comment: @CrisanComisAnca, I've answered the question you asked, and you've accepted it. My answering does not tie me into a support role with you moving forward. If you have a new question, feel free to post a new one, but please note, this site does not provide solutions to questions, which you've not attempted yourself. If you use my second code as a guide, you can incorporate an incrementing counter into the `for` loop, and use that as the argument instead of `%%~nG`. Using the site search, you should find plenty of examples of incrementing for loops under the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, you can adapt.

Comment: @CrisanComisAnca, I will also add however, that I see not good reason to create shortcuts, with non descriptive names. I would consider it foolish to create shortcuts where the end user would need to go into its properties, or hover over it, if that is enabled, just to find out what the linked target is.